# unable to load shared object R_X11.so?

Tags: r, julia, x11

I'm using PhyloPlots in Julia to plot something but the error below showed and I haven't figured out how to fix it.

does anyone know how to fix it? thanks a lot for helping

```
julia> plot(astraltree)
ERROR: REvalError: Warning in grSoftVersion() :
  unable to load shared object '/home/liao/R-4.0.0//modules//R_X11.so':
  /home/liao/R-4.0.0//modules//R_X11.so: undefined symbol: R_ClassSymbol
Warning in cairoVersion() :
  unable to load shared object '/home/liao/R-4.0.0//library/grDevices/libs//cairo.so':
  /home/liao/R-4.0.0//library/grDevices/libs//cairo.so: undefined symbol: R_NilValue
Error in (function (display = "", width, height, pointsize, gamma, bg,  : 
  X11 module cannot be loaded
```

I have shearched some issues about missing R_X11.so and tried code in this page  https://askubuntu.com/questions/213678/how-to-install-x11-xorg and installed X11 but nothing changes...

Comment: Are you able to load it from inside of R?